# How do you create graphs in web apps?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this question is probably very basic, but I am a beginner so I hope it is justified. I tried searching but could not really find anything basic on the topic. So... if I have a web app with users that are generating certain numbers over time and I want to create a pie chart and scatter plot of this data how would I do this? I thought of making a bunch of jpgs with different charts at different values but that would be ridiculous so I am assuming there is an easier way to do this. Is this true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/):

[image: Google Charts Examples] 
[image: Google Charts Examples] 
[image: Google Charts Examples]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to dive down deep into the hard core javascript and create all the visuals yourself, jquery has a bunch of plug-ins and extensions that can possibly help you get what you want done easier. Take a look here 
http://www.jqplot.com/

maybe it can get you started in the direction you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using Flot, which is a jQuery addon. It is quite easy to use and it has very good documentation: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 approaches:

- The classical (and highly compatible) approach is to do what you said yourself and generate these images on server-side. You can generate these images on-the-fly every time someone requests them, or you may cache them somehow - that's up to you.
- A modern approach is to use SVG and Canvas to generate these images client-side with Javascript. Note that some older browsers (like IE6) won't be able to display them.
- Finally, you can use some other browser plugin (like Flash, Java or Silverlight) to generate the images client-side. The drawback again is that the browser has to have the appropriate plugin, and mobile devices are often at a disadvantage here.

Also, as others have noted, there are plenty of frameworks out there that take the hassle away from you. I wouldn't be surprised (but I haven't used any myself so I can't say) if some would even automatically choose whichever of the 3 methods is available.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at, this will require jquery library's tho

6 jquery chart plugins
http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/

Or

Mootools graphs
http://workshop.rs/2010/02/moobargraph-ajax-graph-for-mootools/

Answer (score 0):

Try either http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html or http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/ both are good and free.